# Passing pointer to a member function to a seperate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, pointer-to-member

I'm using OpenGL to display graphics data and custom UI elements. I have a tabbed SDI in which the document windows use borderless windows as viewports, each viewport contains a separate thread to run the GL drawing operations only, while all other operations (mouse, keyboard, etc) are/should be dealt with in the viewport callback. The graphics thread is created using _beginthreadex;

```
void ViewportController::create(){
    hThreadHandle = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(
        _beginthreadex(NULL,
            0,
            &threadProc,
            (void*)lpThreadController,
            0,
            &uiThreadID)
        );
    if (hThreadHandle == 0)
    {
        throw std::exception("Failed to create thread");
    }
}
```

with the *start_address* function containing a loop using PeekMessage to allow the viewport to pass messages to the graphics thread, with the ThreadController class passed as the *arglist* argument;

```
unsigned __stdcall ViewportController::threadProc(void* pArguments)
{
    ThreadController* ctrl = static_cast<ThreadController*>(pArguments);
    MSG mMsg = { 0 };
    bool bStop = false;

    if (wglMakeCurrent(ctrl->getDC(), ctrl->getRC()))
    {
        ctrl->InitGL();

        if (!bStop)
            bStop = (bool)!SendMessage(ctrl->getHandle(), UWM_SHOW, 0, 0);
    }

    while (!bStop)
    {
        while ((bool)PeekMessage(&mMsg, (HWND)(-1), 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            switch (mMsg.message)
            {
            case UWM_DRAW:
                ctrl->draw(mMsg.lParam, mMsg.lParam);
                break;
            case WM_CLOSE:
                bStop = true;
                break;
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                ctrl->keyDown(mMsg.wParam, mMsg.lParam);
                break;
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                ctrl->lButtonDown(mMsg.lParam, mMsg.lParam);
                break;
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                ctrl->mouseMove(mMsg.lParam, mMsg.lParam);
                break;
            case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
                ctrl->mouseWheel(mMsg.lParam, mMsg.lParam);
                break;
            case WM_PAINT:
                ctrl->paint();
                break;
            case WM_SIZE:
                ctrl->size(mMsg.lParam, mMsg.lParam);
                break;
            default:
                return 0;
            }

            SwapBuffers(ctrl->getDC());
        }
    }
    _endthreadex(0);
    return 0;
}
```

At the moment I have all the custom UI elements (text, edit boxes, etc) contained in the ThreadController class. This makes dynamic creation of the UI very difficult and more importantly defeats the object of having a graphics-only pipeline, so what I'd like to do is this;

1. Declare functions in the viewport thread that draw the data and UI elements;

```
void ViewportController::drawSomeStuff()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    /*get the appropriate cameras projection matrix*/

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    /*get the same cameras modelview matrix*/

    /*Lots of stuff beginning with "gl" goes here*/
}

void ViewportController::drawSomeOtherStuff()
{
    /*See above*/
}

void ViewportController::drawSomeDifferentOtherStuffMaybeAnEditBox()
{
    /*See above*/
}
```

and a "dummy" function with the same signature in the ThreadController  class;

```
void drawSomeStuff(){}
```

2. Pass a pointer to the required function to the graphics thread using PostThreadMessage();

```
typedef void (ViewportController::*RenderThreadFn)(); // declare pointer typedef in the ViewportController class

void ViewportController::size(){
RenderThreadFn pRenderFrame = &ViewportController::drawSomeStuff/*drawSomeOtherStuff*//*drawSomeDifferentOtherStuffMaybeAnEditBox*/;
PostThreadMessage(uiThreadID, UWM_DRAW, 0,reinterpret_cast<LPARAM(&pRenderFrame));
}
```

3. Catch PeekMessage() in the graphics thread and execute the function;

```
typedef void (ThreadController::*RenderThreadFn)(); // declare pointer typedef in the ThreadController class

ThreadController::draw(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    RenderThreadFn* pRenderFrame = reinterpret_cast<RenderThreadFn*>(lParam); // get the pointer - everything up to here works 
    (*this.*pRenderFrame)(); // Executing the function here does not work
}
```

4. Give myself a raise for just being so damn good at everything.

This does not work. Obviously the pointers in each class have different definitions, but I don't know how to get around that, or how else I could achieve the same result.

I would be extremely grateful for any guidance on this, I've tried a few things, like inheriting a common class for both the viewport and thread controller classes and defining the typedef for the pointer in that, but I'm still very much a beginner and my problem-solving isn't much more advanced or productive than just randomly smushing the keyboard.

Any ideas on how this can be done? Can it be done at all? Is it a good idea or should I be using a completely different method to get what I want? Please help if you can, I'll remember you when I'm rich and famous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostMessage is not a great way to marshall function pointers and work work items between threads.  You're better off just inventing your own thread-safe data structure and queuing work items to the the render thread.

But if you are really bent on passing a function using PostMessage... then `std::function` combo'd with a lambda could work.

Declare this in a common header file:

```
struct MyCustomMessage
{
    std::function<void()> fn;
};
```

From the ViewPortController thread, do this to "send" the function invocation to the other thread.

```
MyCustomMessage *pMsg = new MyCustomMessage();
pMsg->fn = [this](){
    this->DrawSomeStuff();
};
PostThreadMessage(uiThreadID, UWM_DRAW, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(pMsg);
```

In the other thread:

```
ThreadController::draw(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

     MyCustomMessage* pMsg = reinterpret_cast<MyCustomMessage*>(lParam);

     pMsg->fn();

     delete pMsg;
}
```

Comment: There is no problem postMessaging whole object references to other threads, assuming that you ensure adequate lifetimes.  You can new/dispose or, better, create a pool of them so that they can be recycled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Active-Object-Pattern to send data into your thread via a Concurrent-Queue. An active Object ( check the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object) entry ) encapsulates the thread-function and a concurrent-queue to enqueue commands to this thread. To send commands you could so something like:

```
struct Command {
    int id;
    std::function<void()> fn;
    Command(int id_, std::function<void()> &fn, size_t size){ ... }
};
MyActiveObject object;
Command *drawCmd = new Command(DrawUiEvent, func); 
object.enqueue(drawCmd);
```

This will help to solve issues when a lot of updates must be proceeded by your thread-function because of much user-interaction or something different.